# how to create empty parameter in in pytorch tensor variable

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

```
from torch import FloatTensor

def new_parameter(*size): #1024
    out = torch.nn.Parameter(FloatTensor(*size), requires_grad=True)
    torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(out)
    return out
```

at = new_parameter(1024, 1)

output is

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.0203],
        [-0.0043],
        [-0.0386],
        ...,
        [-0.0084],
        [-0.0289],
        [-0.0188]], requires_grad=True)
```

similarway we can create

```
bt=torch.randn((1024,1),requires_grad=True)
```

output also same

```
tensor([[-1.5478],
        [ 1.5060],
        [ 0.1580],
        ...,
        [ 0.9754],
        [ 0.1699],
        [ 0.2062]], requires_grad=True)
```

are there any differences in a tensor variable the above two ways? please explain the above code in simply

Answer (score 1):

The first method will initialize a random float tensor, then wrap it with [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html). *Which is generally used to register than tensor as a parameter to a [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) (not seen here)*. A utility function [`nn.init.xavier_normal_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html?highlight=xavier_normal_#torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_) is then applied on that parameter to initialize its values.

The second method only initializes a random float tensor.